# How to insert smooth transition in show-hide div with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, css

How I can insert a smooth transition when the "fixed menu" appears?

I'm using the property `transition` but it's not working.

What I'm doing wrong?

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {

var scrollPos;   
var menu_mobile = document.getElementById("menu_mobile");
scrollPos = window.scrollY;

  if(scrollPos > 108){
    menu_mobile.style.display = "initial";
    menu_mobile.style.transform = "translateY(0%)";
    menu_mobile.style.top = "0";
    menu_mobile.style.transition = "all 0.3s";
  }
  if(scrollPos < 108){
  menu_mobile.style.display = "none";
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.menu-mobile{
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 background: #ff008a;
 z-index: 99;
 transform: translateY(-240%);
 transition: all 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}

.aux{
  height: 1500px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
 <section class="menu-mobile container no-margin" id="menu_mobile">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center no-margin">
   <h2 class="titulo-menu-mobile">TEXT TEXT TEXT</h2>
  </div>
 </section>
  
  <section class="aux"></section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `transition` the `display` property. You want to use `opacity` instead, though this *may* create layout issues depending on the rest of your page layout because an element with `opacity: 0;` will still occupy space on the page.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {

var scrollPos;   
var menu_mobile = document.getElementById("menu_mobile");
scrollPos = window.scrollY;

  if(scrollPos > 108){
    menu_mobile.style.opacity = "1";
    menu_mobile.style.transform = "translateY(0%)";
    menu_mobile.style.top = "0";
    menu_mobile.style.transition = "all 0.3s";
  }
  if(scrollPos < 108){
  menu_mobile.style.opacity = "0";
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.menu-mobile{
 opacity: 0;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 background: #ff008a;
 z-index: 99;
 transform: translateY(-240%);
 transition: all 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}

.aux{
  height: 1500px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
 <section class="menu-mobile container no-margin" id="menu_mobile">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center no-margin">
   <h2 class="titulo-menu-mobile">TEXT TEXT TEXT</h2>
  </div>
 </section>
  
  <section class="aux"></section>
```

And here's the same code cleaned up and toggling a class when the menu should appear, instead of manually applying the javascript changes. The only visible difference in the browser is that this technique will `translateY()` the menu when you scroll up/down after the menu has already slid down once, and your original code didn't do that.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {

  var scrollPos = window.scrollY,
      menu_mobile = document.getElementById("menu_mobile"),
      threshold = 108;

  if (scrollPos > threshold) {
    menu_mobile.classList.add('open');
  } else {
    menu_mobile.classList.remove('open');
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.menu-mobile {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #ff008a;
  z-index: 99;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}

.open {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  top: 0;
}

.aux {
  height: 1500px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<section class="menu-mobile container no-margin" id="menu_mobile">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center no-margin">
    <h2 class="titulo-menu-mobile">TEXT TEXT TEXT</h2>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="aux"></section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip of using the `opacity` instead of  `display`. I really didn't know that hahah